# Using fast Fourier transform (FFT) to create a log[x*S(x)] vs log x plot

Tags: r, fft

I am attempting to make a plot of log[x*y] vs log x the issue being that x times the function (y) gives me the errors.

```
x = seq(from =0, to=18000, by = 1)
y = fft(variable, dim(x))
y = y*x

plot(x,y,log= "xy")
```

There are 18000 values of y so when I use 0 to 18000 I get this error:
Error in y <= 0 : invalid comparison with complex values

And when I make my x sequence any larger than 0 I get this error:
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Comment: please add the necessary packages (`stats` for the fft) as well as the `variable`

Comment: `y` is imaginary, thus `plot(y, type = "l")` maybe?